# Which application for shared latex project?

Tags: latex, shared-folders, github

I will start working on a .tex (Latex) paper with a colleague and I would like to know if there is any application that enables both of us to work remotely on the same project, even better if github based. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the source code for the software is on github or that software itself is a github client?   git is a staging and merging tool which requires each person to "pull" and "push" to create "revisions".  So there's no "live" editing.  Or do you mean "both of us to work remotely" as more something like Google Docs or Apache OpenOffice Online have a carat displayed where each person is editing?

Comment: ShareLaTeX/Overleaf has Github support if you pay for a subscription. Are you looking for a free solution?

Comment: @Steve we need a free tool for now.

Comment: @tudor Having a tool like GoogleDocs Would be great, but to start it would be sufficient to have a latex editor and authors upload changes once in a while.